# Sails cannot connect to remote Redis Server in Dev Environment V1.1.0

Tags: sails.js

I am trying to configure persistent sessions through a remote server with redis.

under sails.config.session I am configuring the following code to connect to my Server

```
module.exports.session = {
 adapter: '@sailshq/connect-redis',
 url:"redis://:pass@157.xxx.xxx.xxx:6379/0",
 prefix: 'sess:',
 secret: "secretSailsSessionDataHere",
 cookie: {
    maxAge: 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000
  },
}
```

When I lift Sails with:

```
 sails lift --redis or sails lift
```

The connection defaults to my localhost redis server. If I shutdown my local server it says connection refused from 127.0.0.1 when my server address is xxx.xxx.xxx It also spits out the following error

```
Redis connection manager failed unexpectedly.  Details: Error: Error emitted from Redis client.
Error details:ReplyError: ERR invalid DB index
```

Any suggestions on how I can configure module.exports.sessions to use the remote server?